# checking R code for possible problems ... NOTE

Tags: r, package, cran

After run `devtools::check(cran=TRUE)`

This is the warning message I get.
I tried to add those "imports" into NAMESPACE directly. But it doesn't work as NAMESPACE is generated by roxygen2 so that I can't edit by hand.
However, how can I edit those extra imports?
I really wonder where should I start fixing those warnings. Thanks for helping!!!

```
checking R code for possible problems ... NOTE
  SeasonalityTest: no visible global function definition for 'acf'
  Smoothing_ts2: no visible global function definition for
    'BoxCox.lambda'
  Smoothing_ts2: no visible global function definition for 'BoxCox'
  Smoothing_ts2: no visible global function definition for 'InvBoxCox'
  Smoothing_ts2: no visible global function definition for 'loess'
  diss.cort: no visible global function definition for 'dist'
  generate_ts_with_target_ts: no visible global function definition for
    'nsdiffs'
  generate_ts_with_target_ts: no visible global function definition for
    'InvBoxCox'
  generate_ts_with_target_ts: no visible global function definition for
    'BoxCox'
  pars2x1: no visible global function definition for 'ndiffs'
  pars2x1: no visible global function definition for 'nsdiffs'
  scalets01: no visible global function definition for 'tsp<-'
  scalets01: no visible global function definition for 'tsp'
  Undefined global functions or variables:
    BoxCox BoxCox.lambda InvBoxCox acf dist loess ndiffs nsdiffs tsp
    tsp<-
  Consider adding
    importFrom("stats", "acf", "dist", "loess", "tsp", "tsp<-")
  to your NAMESPACE file.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the packages to import in each function definition using the `@import` or `@importFrom` keywords in the `Roxygen` description:

```
#' Title
#'
#' @return 
#' @importFrom stats acf dist loess tsp tsp<-
#' @export
#'
#' @examples
foo <- function() {}
```

NAMESPACE will be automatically modified after running `devtools::document()`, see [R Packages : Imports](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/namespace.html#imports).
You have to modify the DESCRIPTION file manually.

Comment: Thank you for kindly reply. Huge help! Wish a good day :)

Comment: Glad it could help! Would you mind accepting the answer so that others also know it works ;)